# POST request does not arrive properly httpClient - ionic - PHP

Tags: php, ionic4

I'm creating a REST API in PHP. The service `login` is:

```
<?php

include_once 'libs/Database.php';

header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");


Database::getPDO();
$myObj = null;
if ( Database::check($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    $myObj = array('message' => "Verified", 'success' => true);
} else {
    $myObj = array('message' => "Unauthorized", 'username' => $_POST['username'], 'success' => false);
}

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

echo $myJSON;
?>
```

And as you may see, I'm accessing `$_POST` global variable.

- Postman: sending a POST request with header `x-www-form-urlenconded` and specifying the keys and values, the server does capture such keys.
- Ionic: sending a POST request using `HttpClient` will not work. (The server captures `null` for both keys, `username` and `password`).

This is the code of the provider:

```
  login(user, pass, url) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
    return this.http.post(url, "username="+user+"&"+"password="+pass, httpOptions);
  }
```

I'm wondering how the `body` should be formatted, and according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) should be like I have done (`username=user&password=pass`). By the way, all parameters are not null when the `login` function is called, hence, the problem is in the request.

For those of you interested, the answer of the server is:

> {message: "Unauthorized", username: null, success: false}

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you're using Angular's HttpClient, try to specify which type you're sending via POST: try to do something as `this.http.post<string>(url, 'string', opts);`.
I also suggest you to take a look at what you're sending as request via Chrome's Inspector (F12 on windows/linux, Cmd+Options+I on Mac), tab network. Obviously you must open it before sending request to be captured by DevTools. If you're debugging directly through the phone, on Windows/Linux you can use tab Remote Devices, on Mac you can use Safari

Comment: I'm using `httpClient`. The weird thing is that by setting this `"username="+user+"&password="+pass` as the `body`, the server does capture `username` but not `password`.  With respect to the network tab in the chrome dev tools, I can just see the responses but not the queries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm copying my comment as an answer 'cause I want to post a photo.

Assuming you're using Angular's HttpClient, try to specify which type you're sending via POST: try to do something as `this.http.post<string>(url, 'string', opts);`.

I also suggest you to take a look at what you're sending as request via Chrome's Inspector (<kbd>F12</kbd> on windows/linux, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Options</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Mac), Network tab.

Obviously you must open it before sending request to be captured by DevTools. If you're debugging directly through the phone, on Windows/Linux you can use Remote Devices tab on Chrome's DevTools, or Safari on Mac.

An example using Chrome's DevTools:

[image]